# Saving Data in Dymos Changes Optimisation and Simulation Results

Tags: openmdao

I had a similar issue as expressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538722/dymos-how-can-i-record-and-visualize-subsystem-inputs-outputs). I followed [Rob Flack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754536/rob-falck)'s answer but had issues. If anyone could help me out, I would appreciate it.

I used the code suggested in the answer but had an issue: It changed the simulation results. I added a line in the script for the min_time_climb example that goes like this:

```
phase.add_timeseries_output('aero.mach', units=None, shape=(1,), output_name = "recorded_mach")
```

I used the name "recorded_mach" so as to not override anything else Dymos may or may not have been recording. The issue is that the default Altitude (h) vs. time graph actually changed, both the discrete points and simulation curve. I ended up recording 4 variables with similar commands to what I have just shown and that somehow made the simulation track better with the discrete optimisation points on the graph. When I recorded another 4 variables on top of that, it made it track worse. I find this very strange because I don't see why recording the simulation should change its output.

Have you ever come across this? Any insight you could provide into the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Notes:

I have somewhat modified the example in order to fit a different sutuation (Different thrust and fuel burn data, different lift and drag polars, different height and speed goals) before implimenting the code described above. However, it was working fine still.

Answer (score 0):

Without some kind of example to look at, I can only make an educated guess. So please take my answer with a grain of salt.

Some optimization problems have very ill conditioned Jacobians and/or KKT matrices (which you as a user would not normally see, but can be problematic none the less). There are many potential causes for this ill conditioning, but some common ones are very large derivatives (i.e. approaching infinity) or very larger ranges in magnitude between different derivatives. Another common cuase is the introduction of a saddle point, where you have infinite numbers of answers that are all equally good. Sometimes you can fix the problem with scaling, other times you need to re-work the problem formulation.

Ill conditioning has two bad effects on the optimizer. First, it makes it very hard for the numerics inside to comput inverses which are needed to compute step sizes. It will get **an** answer, but may be highly subject to numerical noise. Second,  it may prevent certain approximations (like BFGS) from performing well in the first place.

In these cases, small changes in execution order or extra steps (e.g. case recoding) can cause the optimizer to take a different path. If you're finding that the path ultimately leads one case to work and another to fail, then you might have a marginally stable problem where you got lucky one time and not the other.

Look carefully for anything singular-like in your jacobian. 0 rows/columns? a constraint that happens to be satisfied, but still has a 0 row is a problem that comes up in Dymos cases if you forget to add additional degrees of freedom when you add constraints. Saddle points also arise if you're careful with your objective.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you so much for answering. I was at a loss and this is really helpful. I  realised that it was shooting an error similar to the one in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67477528/derivatives-warning-doesnt-make-sense). This confirmed (I think) that I had zero rows in my Jacobian that were associated with the path constraints of a few variables (h and mach). Once I commented out these constraints, the results converged much better. This happens no matter how many states I record but the actual result still changes depending on this. Any further insight?

Comment: 0 rows are exactly the kind of thing that creates numerical instabilities. I don't have much more insight for you though. It sounds like you just need to work on scaling a bit, and possibly check for any other sources of singularity in your formulation. Do you have any controls that don't link strongly enough to the objective/constraints?

Comment: Hi Justin, I forgot to thank you before. Thanks! I ended up solving the problem by using boundary constraints instead of set_val